# Quais são as vantagens de se utilizar o SplFixedArray ao invés de um array?

Tags: php, array

Quais são as vantagens de se utilizar o SplFixedArray ao invés de um array?

Quais são as vantagens de se fixar um valor para um "array" (no PHP) ?

Exemplo com `array`:

```
$arr = array();

$arr[0] = 'Stack';

$arr[1] = 'Overflow';

$arr[2] = 'blablabla';
```

Exemplo com`SplFixedArray`

```
$arr = new SplFixedArray(2);

$arr[0] = 'Stack';

$arr[1] = 'Overflow';

$arr[2] = 'blablabla'; // RunTimeException: Index invalid or out of range
```

Comment: "um valor para um array" queres dizer um tamanho? Se for isso a vantagem é ocupares exatamente o espaço de memória que queres.

Comment: SplFixedArray é mais rápida do que matrizes, e tem um menor consumo de memória.

Comment: Por quê?????????

Comment: Porque já foram feitos testes, e mais testes, de uma olhada [neste artigo](http://www.johnciacia.com/2011/02/01/array-vs-splfixedarray/), saberá o por quê!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A vantagem é que ele permite uma **rápida implementacao de Array**.
Como ilustrado pelos benchmarks realizados pelo autor deste [artigo](http://www.johnciacia.com/2011/02/01/array-vs-splfixedarray/):
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Além disso, o consumo de memória de SplFixedArray é realmente menor, mas perceptível apenas para uma grande quantidade de elementos do array. Porque SplFixedArray é tecnicamente uma instância de uma classe, ao contrário de arrays tradicionais.